# CKEditor strange style change behavior

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

If you are going to make a piece of text bold/italic or want to change its font size in CKEditor, you have to select it, but other editors (such as TinyMCE) or even MS Word allow user to apply styles without a need to select the text, i.e. if no text is selected, current word style (cursor position) is changed. Is there any way to perform such an action in CKEditor? Any option or parameter?

Comment: Have you checked their plugin section? They might have something worth using for that type of function. http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I looked there but couldn't find anything matching my needs. I don't know if it is a bug or developers have just forgotten it!

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. I do think it's a nice feature added to other software/Interfaces that you might see in future versions. Please see my answer below for workaround.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of workaround:

- If you're using your mouse, just double click the word
- If you want to do it while typing (OSX) Option + Shift + Right arrow (Win) Ctrl + Shift + Right arrow will select the next word.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks Trig! I'll check your suggestions right now.